# Adding an Accordion within Joomla Component Options Screen

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.1

Is it possible to add an accordion to a Joomla 3.x component's options screen, similar to what is presented in Joomla's menu or template parameters screens?

If so, how does would one structure the config.xml file?

Example illustration of what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com_config manages that view and it pretty much expects a standard structure. You might be able to do a layout override for it as long as you don't break the other extensions. You could for example make it conditional on the option being your extension.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use an override @elin. I was hoping there would be an easier way to organize all the fields (other than using the tabs at the top) :)